Custom Tree Node in PSTricks
I've produced a tree with pst-tree but the nodes aren't quite what I want.  Here is the MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-tree}

\SpecialCoor

\newcommand{\BiBox}{%
\begin{pspicture}(2,1)
  \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridlabels=0](2,1)
  \dotnode*[dotscale=1.15](0.7,0.65){L-\pspred-\the\psnodecnt}
  \dotnode*[dotscale=1.15](1.3,0.65){R-\pspred-\the\psnodecnt}
\end{pspicture}}

% A tree node, with two boxes for left/right pointers
\newcommand{\DataNode}[1]{{%
\psset{nodesepB=0}
\TCX{\begin{tabular}{c}#1\\\\\BiBox{}\end{tabular}}
\pnode(L-\pspred-\the\psnodecnt){\pssucc}}}

% A tree node macro, updating the position of the node above
\newcommand{\TCX}[1]{%
\Tcircle[ref=t]{#1}
\pnode(R-\pspred){\pspred}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\DataNode{x}

\psset{levelsep=120pt}
\noindent\pstree{\DataNode{a}}{%
   \pstree{\DataNode{b}}{%
       \DataNode{e}
       \DataNode{f}
   }
   \pstree{\DataNode{c}}{%
       \DataNode{g}
       \DataNode{h}
   }
}

\end{document}

It was customized from the first binary tree example at TUG.org here.  But what I really want is a circle with a T-bar at the bottom for the left/right pointers and the data above the T.
I was thinking I could shrink the circle I have now and clip the content such that the pointer boxes chop off a the outer-lower corners.  But I'm not sure that's feasible or best.  I've tried with calc and fp to get sizes and shrink the circle, but couldn't get anything working.
Bonus points if you can let/make the node's pointers turn to slashes in leaves (to represent a nullptr)!  (If it helps, I'm not totally attached to the dot nodes and would be fine with pnodes instead.)
Edit:
This is what I'd like the nodes to look like:

The b and c nodes have nullptrs as discussed above.
Hope this helps clarify!

something like this??

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-tree}

\newcommand\BiBox[1][1]{%
  \begin{pspicture}(2,1)
        \psline(1,-0.8)(1,0.2)\psline(-0.5,0.2)(2.5,0.2)
        \pnode(0.5,-0.1){L-\pspred-\the\psnodecnt}
        \pnode(1.5,-0.1){R-\pspred-\the\psnodecnt}
        \ifnum#1=0
          \psline(1,0.2)(0,-0.4)\psline(1,0.2)(2,-0.4)
        \fi
  \end{pspicture}}

% A tree node, with two boxes for left/right pointers
\newcommand\DataNode[2][1]{{%
        \psset{nodesepB=0}
        \TCX{\begin{tabular}{c}#2\\\\\BiBox[#1]\end{tabular}}
        \pnode(L-\pspred-\the\psnodecnt){\pssucc}}}

% A tree node macro, updating the position of the node above
\newcommand\TCX[1]{%
    \Tcircle[ref=t]{#1}
    \pnode(R-\pspred){\pspred}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    
    \DataNode[0]{x}\DataNode{x}
    
    \psset{levelsep=120pt}
    \noindent\pstree{\DataNode{a}}{%
        \pstree{\DataNode{b}}{%
            \DataNode[0]{e}
            \DataNode[0]{f}
        }
        \pstree{\DataNode{c}}{%
            \DataNode[0]{g}
            \DataNode[0]{h}
        }
    }
    
\end{document}


This is nice.  Thanks.  But I was expecting the T to be rightside-up.  smile  Basically like the boxes were but with the outside-lower corners clipped.  I'm thinking about how to flip this and my only 'concern' is that I can't get the top of the T to extend to the edges of the circle.  I wish I could draw what I see in my head but my skills with pencil and paper are just as bad.  chuckle  And the tail of the T will be over the bottom edge of the circle, as well.  Like I said, I tried all kinds of width and FPeval to resize things and couldn't figure it out.  But thanks for this effort!

create a small picture of what you want...

I've edited the original post to contain my best attempt at drawing this.  Hope it helps!

See edited answer ...

Thanks!  That's awesome!
